# How can we check the data sent to the email client is in encrypted or not?

Tags: html, security, networking, passwords

I have a forgot password page that sends the auto generated password to the given mail id, i have to check the this password travel encrypted in network or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your situation the when the password is sent to an email address via the forget password option then there is no way you can check it that what the server sends to the email client.

You forget password is received by the web server and the server then connects to email server and you only get the confirmation that the password has been sent to the requested email or not. The connection between the web server and the email server is not intercept able by the client side until and unless you lye between the web server and email server.

If you have curiosity about the email sending mechanism technique then refer to this article here:

http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/can-email-ever-be-secure/